# can't connect to local server by ssh

Tags: ssh

i am on mac book pro and i install ubuntu server in parallel desktop, so i want to use the ssh to connect the virtual machine,how to do it

Comment: What networking mode have you set up the VM in?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few other questions.  Indeed, what networking mode's setup?  Is SSHD installed and running, can you ping the machine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your VMs are not connecting via NAT within the hypervisor (Parallel).